# UIButton on Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a Custom UITableViewCell that has a couple buttons. When the code was all under one view controller, my button was declared like this:

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(myButtonAction:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton setTitle:@"Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 80, 72, 37);
[self addSubview:myButton];
```

Last night I subclassed UITableViewCell, so the code became this:

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[myButton addTarget:viewController
             action:@selector(myButtonAction:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton setTitle:@"Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 80, 72, 37);
[self addSubview:damageButton];
```

Since doing this, however, pushing the button on any cell causes the action to only effect the first row in the table, and I'm not sure why.

Action code:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
UIView *contentView = [button superview];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:cell];

//do something with objectAtIndex:indexPath.row
```

I understand it's common to set the Tag Property to indexPath.row for using a UIButton in a table view. However, I'm using two separate arrays in the data source to populate two different sections of the TableView, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: maybe it's just me but the code for the button looks exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe your code isn't really like that, but you're not adding the same button you're creating (myButton vs damageButton).

Comment: @fluchtpunkt - The only difference is the target is a view controller I'm passing as a property

Comment: @jv42 was renaming things to make it generic, missed that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, in the end, was that I was adding the subview to the cell object and not the contentview of the cell object. I changed the button code to this and it was resolved:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[button superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't subclass UITableViewCell (or UITableView), it's usually unnecessary and can cause problems. Table cells have a `contentView` which is a great place for customization.

Recommended reading:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

and then:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html

Comment: Hmmm. I was subclassing UITableViewCell to deal with a problem with scrolling performance I was having. Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: I'm subclassing UITableViewCell all the time to avoid putting lots of presentation code in ViewControllers, putting it in isolated cell classes instead.

Comment: But I agree with the article you've linked: do not abuse subclassing, and specifically, do not use it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Actual drawing is sometimes better done in the contentView of a UITableViewCell (which you can have a rendering object for), rather than by the UITableViewCell itself.